# Show out of stock product for configurable product Magento 2.1.13

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, swatches

I want to show all sizes of configurable products.
Like i have three size S, M, L and L is in Out of stock than it should be visible swatches with cross.

In configuration product i am enable show out of stock product visible.

But still out of stock swatches is not showing

Answer (score -1):

To be able to activate this configuration go to **Products -> Catalog**, there we choose any product and we go to the option of **Quantity**. Under it, there is the option **"advanced inventory"**, click on it and select the first box that says **Use configuration options** found under **Manage stock.**

This configuration will show all the swatches